# Memory allocated by dma_alloc_coherent corrupted by python

Tags: python, linux, linux-device-driver, memory-corruption

I have a UIO kernel driver which will allocate 92M bytes memory by dma_alloc_coherent(I have set CMA size to 256M so it will always succeed), and I can see the physical address and size of this memory in sysfs. The range is **0x30bc2000~0x367c2000**(0x30bc2000 + 0x05c00000).

```
root@ubuntu-arm:~# cat /sys/class/uio/uio0/maps/map1/addr
0x30bc2000
root@ubuntu-arm:~# cat /sys/class/uio/uio0/maps/map1/size
0x05c00000
```

Then I run my python program, but I found the code sections of python corrupt the memory allocated by my UIO driver, they are using the same physcal memory!
First I got the virtual address mapping from /proc/self/maps:

```
root@ubuntu-arm:~# cat /proc/2337/maps
00010000-0020d000 r-xp 00000000 b3:02 12130      /usr/bin/python2.7
0021c000-0021d000 r--p 001fc000 b3:02 12130      /usr/bin/python2.7
0021d000-00277000 rw-p 001fd000 b3:02 12130      /usr/bin/python2.7
00277000-00340000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [heap]
b6bcf000-b6c0f000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
b6c0f000-b6c13000 r-xp 00000000 b3:02 2974       /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/mmap.arm-linux-gnueabihf.so
b6c13000-b6c22000 ---p 00004000 b3:02 2974       /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/mmap.arm-linux-gnueabihf.so
b6c22000-b6c23000 r--p 00003000 b3:02 2974       /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/mmap.arm-linux-gnueabihf.so
b6c23000-b6c24000 rw-p 00004000 b3:02 2974       /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/mmap.arm-linux-gnueabihf.so
b6c24000-b6d24000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
b6d24000-b6d8b000 r-xp 00000000 b3:02 15868      /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libm-2.23.so
b6d8b000-b6d9a000 ---p 00067000 b3:02 15868      /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libm-2.23.so
b6d9a000-b6d9b000 r--p 00066000 b3:02 15868      /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libm-2.23.so
b6d9b000-b6d9c000 rw-p 00067000 b3:02 15868      /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libm-2.23.so
b6d9c000-b6dad000 r-xp 00000000 b3:02 955        /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libz.so.1.2.8
b6dad000-b6dbc000 ---p 00011000 b3:02 955        /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libz.so.1.2.8
b6dbc000-b6dbd000 r--p 00010000 b3:02 955        /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libz.so.1.2.8
b6dbd000-b6dbe000 rw-p 00011000 b3:02 955        /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libz.so.1.2.8
b6dbe000-b6dc0000 r-xp 00000000 b3:02 15867      /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libutil-2.23.so
b6dc0000-b6dcf000 ---p 00002000 b3:02 15867      /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libutil-2.23.so
b6dcf000-b6dd0000 r--p 00001000 b3:02 15867      /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libutil-2.23.so
b6dd0000-b6dd1000 rw-p 00002000 b3:02 15867      /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libutil-2.23.so
b6dd1000-b6dd3000 r-xp 00000000 b3:02 15862      /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libdl-2.23.so
b6dd3000-b6de2000 ---p 00002000 b3:02 15862      /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libdl-2.23.so
b6de2000-b6de3000 r--p 00001000 b3:02 15862      /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libdl-2.23.so
b6de3000-b6de4000 rw-p 00002000 b3:02 15862      /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libdl-2.23.so
b6de4000-b6eba000 r-xp 00000000 b3:02 15882      /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc-2.23.so
b6eba000-b6eca000 ---p 000d6000 b3:02 15882      /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc-2.23.so
b6eca000-b6ecc000 r--p 000d6000 b3:02 15882      /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc-2.23.so
b6ecc000-b6ecd000 rw-p 000d8000 b3:02 15882      /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc-2.23.so
b6ecd000-b6ed0000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
b6ed0000-b6ee1000 r-xp 00000000 b3:02 15872      /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpthread-2.23.so
b6ee1000-b6ef0000 ---p 00011000 b3:02 15872      /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpthread-2.23.so
b6ef0000-b6ef1000 r--p 00010000 b3:02 15872      /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpthread-2.23.so
b6ef1000-b6ef2000 rw-p 00011000 b3:02 15872      /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpthread-2.23.so
b6ef2000-b6ef4000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
b6ef4000-b6f0c000 r-xp 00000000 b3:02 15876      /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/ld-2.23.so
b6f14000-b6f16000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
b6f1a000-b6f1b000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
b6f1b000-b6f1c000 r--p 00017000 b3:02 15876      /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/ld-2.23.so
b6f1c000-b6f1d000 rw-p 00018000 b3:02 15876      /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/ld-2.23.so
bef1b000-bef3c000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [stack]
befda000-befdb000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0          [sigpage]
ffff0000-ffff1000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0          [vectors]
```

I try to convert the virtual address to physical address by /proc/pid/pagemap.
Starting from 0x00010000-0020d000  (code section of python I think):

```
root@ubuntu-arm:~# ./virt_to_phys 2337 0x10000
Big endian? 0
Vaddr: 0x10000, Page_size: 4096, Entry_size: 8
Reading /proc/2337/pagemap at 0x80
[0]0xbc [1]0xb9 [2]0x3 [3]0x0 [4]0x0 [5]0x0 [6]0x0 [7]0xa1
Result: 0xa10000000003b9bc
PFN: 0x3b9bc (0x3b9bc000)
root@ubuntu-arm:~#
root@ubuntu-arm:~# ./virt_to_phys 2337 0x20000
Big endian? 0
Vaddr: 0x20000, Page_size: 4096, Entry_size: 8
Reading /proc/2337/pagemap at 0x100
[0]0xd0 [1]0xb6 [2]0x3 [3]0x0 [4]0x0 [5]0x0 [6]0x0 [7]0xa1
Result: 0xa10000000003b6d0
PFN: 0x3b6d0 (0x3b6d0000)
root@ubuntu-arm:~#
root@ubuntu-arm:~# ./virt_to_phys 2337 0x30000
Big endian? 0
Vaddr: 0x30000, Page_size: 4096, Entry_size: 8
Reading /proc/2337/pagemap at 0x180
[0]0x0 [1]0x0 [2]0x0 [3]0x0 [4]0x0 [5]0x0 [6]0x0 [7]0x0
Result: 0x0
Page not present
root@ubuntu-arm:~#
root@ubuntu-arm:~# ./virt_to_phys 2337 0x40000
Big endian? 0
Vaddr: 0x40000, Page_size: 4096, Entry_size: 8
Reading /proc/2337/pagemap at 0x200
[0]0x0 [1]0xb5 [2]0x3 [3]0x0 [4]0x0 [5]0x0 [6]0x0 [7]0xa1
Result: 0xa10000000003b500
PFN: 0x3b500 (0x3b500000)
root@ubuntu-arm:~#
root@ubuntu-arm:~# ./virt_to_phys 2337 0x50000
Big endian? 0
Vaddr: 0x50000, Page_size: 4096, Entry_size: 8
Reading /proc/2337/pagemap at 0x280
[0]0xa5 [1]0x5d [2]0x3 [3]0x0 [4]0x0 [5]0x0 [6]0x0 [7]0xa1
Result: 0xa100000000035da5
PFN: 0x35da5 (0x35da5000)
```

As we can see that virtual address 0x50000 is mapping to physcal address **0x35da5000**, the physical address is just in the range(**0x30bc2000~0x367c2000**) of my UIO driver DMA memory.
My question is why the OS assigns the same memory to different process, any clue?
And here is my OS information:

```
root@ubuntu-arm:~# uname -a
Linux ubuntu-arm 4.9.0-xilinx #1 SMP PREEMPT Mon Jan 10 06:52:07 UTC 2022 armv7l armv7l armv7l GNU/Linux
root@ubuntu-arm:~#
root@ubuntu-arm:~# python --version
Python 2.7.12
```

Thanks.

Comment: It's by design to allow the shared objects to be built independently on the OS memory layout. The address is virtual and it may be the same, no issue here.

Comment: I know the virtual address cound be same,  cuz they can be assigned to different physical memory. But my issue is that the UIO kernel driver and python use the same physical memory, if the driver write data to this memory, actually it is modifying the code section of python process, then I got a segmentation  fault.

Comment: There is a bug in your code, which you have not shown